# What The Heck Did I Just Read?

Tags: story

It was the first of April when I received a letter from my good friend Richard. He never sent me one so I was surprised. I opened it and what came next left me speechless

> kevin, please Help me out! A friend invited me to a place called "Party Place" and they said that the food was "extra spicY" and you know me, i like thAt kind of PaRty food. anyway, where was I again? oh yeah, i went to that place but the reaL place was horrible and almost no one came. one of my Friends texted me that they had Other things to dO. so i decided to Leave that place and juSt go home. when i arriveD home, A note was taped on mY door saying that my family has been kidnapped. what was odd was that he left a clue

Below the letter was the clue that the mysterious kidnapper left

> awnonsa asijdjls jignede kgjljnlnds!

What should I do???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you take all the capital letters in the letters it says "HAPPY APRIL FOOLS DAY"

I suppose...

> Richard is pranking you? 
>  
>  <sub>(Tried to decrypt using a Vigenere cipher, still meaningless...)</sub>

Comment: Yep! correct answer

Comment: The clue was just nonsense actually and the answer lies in the letter

Answer (score 4):

> *It's obvious your good friend Richard and family teamed up together to play an April Fool's Joke! But where were they hiding to watch you? Perhaps his house watching you from a hidden or security camera laughing at you? LOL! Sorry I couldn't help myself. Then I noticed the scrambled letters. Focusing on unscrambling the letters I come up with nothing! Looks like a false lead to me and a time waster in finding the solution but this tactic is what makes it even funnier! My answer is still do "Nothing!" but am I correct?*

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Great answer :) For future reference, always add spoiler tags >! before the important parts of your answer to hide them in case other puzzlers want a chance to solve the puzzle as well! Thanks!

Comment: El-Guest - Sorry I am new to this and it's my first time on here. I thought answers were automatically formatted. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Harriet, no worries at all! If you'd like to learn more, the link for editing help (I still use it all the time!) is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Glad to be of assistance, and happy puzzling!